# Switch input language with Control + Shift on Mac OS X

Tags: objective-c, macos, keyboard

Is it possible to create utility for **Mac OS X 10.8** that will allow to set **Control+Shift** keys combination (or Control+Option, Option+Shift etc.) to switch input language?
For some reason I didn't find a single utility that can provide this kind of functionality, which is very requested by many **Windows->Mac** switchers.
Is it something not possible due to OS limitations?

Comment: The default shortcut for that is `Cmd+Space`. You can change shortcuts, but not to modifier keys (like Control, Option, Shift) *only*.

Comment: I know that already. Question is about implementing this missed functionality, if that is technically possible.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Others have done it, I'm sure you found those tools already.

Comment: No, I actually was not able to find it! maybe I am missing something obvious, but I didn't find ready made tool and thought there should be some specific issue and that is why no one did it. Google gives thousands of new switchers' requests for that feature with no resolution. Can you share link to any tool?

Comment: Look for KeyRemap4MacBook, but consider that Ctrl+Shift/Ctrl+Opt/Opt+Shift in combination with other keys are used for all sorts of things already on Mac (shortcuts, accents) so you're going to introduce a whole lot of issues if you remap those just to switch input source. Also, how hard would it be to learn just one new combination that always works, on any Mac? But hey, just my $.02

Comment: This is a perfectly legitimate question. For example, I use both Windows PC and Mac, and switch between them very often via KVM. In this scenario, keyboard shortcuts should be as close as possible. I don't want to be conscious of what OS I'm currently in when working with text. As for the original question - I was not able to map this combination either.

Comment: The KeyRemap4MacBook System Preferences addon can map alt-shift (or ctrl-shift) to switch languages http://superuser.com/questions/91980/alt-shift-language-switch-on-os-x

Comment: Thanks Igor! Unfortunately, I'm already hooked to cmd+space and managed to avoid Windows completely over last year :-) if you make this answer I'll mark as a right one.

Comment: @NickFrolov I faced the same issue and after not being able to find a reliable solution I've decided to create a small app that does exactly that. It's free and open-source and now I hope that it would also be useful not just to me but also to other people. Cheers! =) https://github.com/VasylBaran/CommandShift

Answer (score 1):

I find a solution with keyboard Maestro editor ! You can record in a hot keys , action to change to a langage to an other .
I have try it with F8 hot key for set US keyboard langage and F9 for French one , pretty fun !